# Nuxt - render HTML on server-side and keep this HTML and all the related assets stored so they never change in the future even if app code changes

Tags: caching, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I am currently working on a Nuxt + Express project which is deployed to AWS. The application is in SSR mode as it is required for the application to render on the server, however, the requirement is to cache the client assets (`dist/client`) in S3 bucket for each build so when a page `/page/{id}` is reached, it will show a version in which it was built in, even if the version of the application changed. We will cache these for several months.

The problem for me is that when the application is built, the assets are generated in the `dist/client`, but for the Nuxt's SSR mode, these headers are dynamically added in the `dist/server`, therefore I am unable to cache them.

Is there any way to have these headers on a client-side using SSR mode?